# Java Update statement issue

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to update the SSN for a customer by searching for them based on the old SSN then updating it.   What am I missing?  This will not return a result even though i know i have matches for ssNum in the database. Thanks.

```
String query = "UPDATE Customers SET ss_num = ('" + updateSsn
                + "') WHERE ss_num = ('" + ssNum + "')";
```

Comment: You should specify your DBMS and the exception that's been thrown

Comment: Please use PreparedStatement with a parameterized query to guard against things like SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `executeUpdate()` method, which doesn't return `ResultSet`, but it will return `numberOfRowsUpdated`

Use `PreparedStatement` instead

Comment: Thanks! It was the executeUpdate() that was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

That type of query is unsafe (vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)). Write your query as follows and use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
String query = "UPDATE Customers SET ss_num = ? WHERE ss_num = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, updateSsn);
ps.setString(2, ssnNum);
```